# jQuery ~ Only get the inner div id name

Tags: jquery

When click the red area it alert 'red', when click the blue area it alert 'blue' and 'red'!
How do make it only alert 'blue' then stop.Because I only need the front of the div name.

http://jsfiddle.net/FFZuD/1/

HTML

```
<div id="block1" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
        <div id="block2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #09F; ">
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('div').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FFZuD/2/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) jquery function. Its better to use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`; because it will be more efficient.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FFZuD/3/)**

```
$('div').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
  //alert($(this).attr('id'));
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Please: `alert($(this).attr('id'));` => `alert(
    this.id);`

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is stopPropagation its prevents the event from bubbling up.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/meo/FFZuD/5/

```
$(".block").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();            
        /*etc...*/
});​​
```